# Seguridad Wcf Autentificacion Username c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice, wcf, servicio

Estoy realizando un servicio web con **WCF** de c# bueno cuando ejecuto el servicio me aparece asi [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y no me pide ninguna validacion o autentificación.

Quisiera poner una autentificación cuando consuma ese servicio requiera pedir un usuario y contraseña.

ya que este servicio va ser consumida por un externo , y si no tiene una seguridad cualquier va consumir mi servicio.

yo quisiera que cuando consuman los externo si es igual el usuario y clave consuma y si no saben que no consuma

si me podrian ayudar.

Este es mi codigo en webconfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="401kApp" loginUrl="/Service1.svc">
        <credentials passwordFormat = "SHA1">

          <user name="UserName1" password="SHA1EncryptedPassword1"/>
        </credentials>
      </forms>
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>

    <add name="CnxUsu" connectionString="wZhyFoK5oBVv3J+J8qRkKIaRggbvPeaMVBpHLf9B1rGNbBU9aUiRfcuxECM078XGyeTfTUN+tk1gpSSUdPdjAc2alNIzOLufj27DOwCocr5S9fUXOfpyl7dXuw2D9U/4NPLP+zcFs5MoMDY8hrRuZA=="/>

  </connectionStrings>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="securitySession">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" establishSecurityContext="true" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>

        <behavior>

          <!-- Para evitar revelar información de los metadatos, establezca los valores siguientes en false antes de la implementación -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- Para recibir detalles de las excepciones en los fallos, con el fin de poder realizar la depuración, establezca el valor siguiente en true. Para no revelar información sobre las excepciones, establézcalo en false antes de la implementación -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>

      </serviceBehaviors>

    </behaviors>

    <protocolMapping>

        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>

    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>

  </system.webServer>


</configuration>
```

Este es mi codigo en .cs

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        NBusquedacampana wsDataBusqueda(string identificacion, string nombres, string correo, string fuente, string idcanal, string ip);

    }

    // Utilice un contrato de datos, como se ilustra en el ejemplo siguiente, para agregar tipos compuestos a las operaciones de servicio.
    [DataContract]

    public class NBusquedacampana
    {
        String _Rpta;
        [DataMember]
        public String Rpta
        {
            get { return _Rpta; }
            set { _Rpta = value; }
        }
    }
```

Este es mi codigo en .svc

```
public NBusquedacampana wsDataBusqueda(string identificacion, string nombres, string correo, string fuente, string idcanal, string ip)
        {
            String _Rpta;

            if(identificacion =="")
            {
                _Rpta = "Ingrese el Dni";
                return new NBusquedacampana() { Rpta = _Rpta };
            }

            if (identificacion ==null)
            {
                _Rpta = "Ingrese el Dni";
                return new NBusquedacampana() { Rpta = _Rpta };
            }

            if (nombres == "")
            {
                _Rpta = "Ingrese el nombre";
                return new NBusquedacampana() { Rpta = _Rpta };
            }
            if (nombres ==null)
            {
                _Rpta = "Ingrese el Dni";
                return new NBusquedacampana() { Rpta = _Rpta };
            }

            if (correo == "")
            {
                _Rpta = "Ingrese el Correo";
                return new NBusquedacampana() { Rpta = _Rpta };
            }
            if (correo ==null)
            {
                _Rpta = "Ingrese el Dni";
                return new NBusquedacampana() { Rpta = _Rpta };
            }
            if (fuente == "")
            {
                _Rpta = "Ingrese la fuente";
                return new NBusquedacampana() { Rpta = _Rpta };
            }
            if (fuente ==null)
            {
                _Rpta = "Ingrese el Dni";
                return new NBusquedacampana() { Rpta = _Rpta };
            }
            if (idcanal == "")
            {
                _Rpta = "Ingrese el canal";
                return new NBusquedacampana() { Rpta = _Rpta };
            }
            if (idcanal ==null)
            {
                _Rpta = "Ingrese el Dni";
                return new NBusquedacampana() { Rpta = _Rpta };
            }
            else
            {
                _Rpta = nECampanas.wsDataBusqueda(identificacion, nombres, correo, fuente, idcanal, ip);
                return new NBusquedacampana() { Rpta = _Rpta };


            }


        }
```

Comment: Tema amplio, quizás consideres revisar [Autenticador de tokens](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/token-authenticator)

Comment: @Davlio Gracias Maestro